# Вставить данные с процедуры в таблицу в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Коллеги, кто-то проходил квест по написанию синтаксиса INSERT #Temp EXEC dbo.Test_Proc @a = @a в MySQL? Это вообще возможно без предварительного создания таблицы в самой вызывающем процедуре? Хотелось бы что-то по аналогии INSERT INTO #Temp CALL dbo.Test_Proc @a = @a;

Comment: Нет такой буквы. В MySQL набор(ы) записей, возвращаемых процедурой, не может быть источником данных запроса. Именно потому что процедура может возвращать несколько наборов (в т.ч. ни одного) данных, причём разной структуры. Если нужно сохранить результат в таблицу, это делается непосредственно в тексте процедуры, явным INSERT INTO.

Comment: @Akina, т.е. если мне нужен подобный синтаксис, я должен в процедуре, с которой вставляю, дописать временную таблицу, куда помимо исходящего датасета буду сохранять его копию, чтобы потом из нее брать данные для других нужд?

Comment: *куда помимо исходящего датасета буду сохранять его копию* Нахрена копию-то? просто пиши в таблицу, а не в выходной поток. А если её ещё и ENGINE=Memory (при условии, что выбираются не гигабайты, конечно), то и вовсе шоколадно.

Comment: В каком плане писать в таблицу? Мне нужно писать в таблицу результат выполнения одной процедуры, а юзать ее в другой)

Comment: В начало первой процедуры добавить `CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE tablename (definition) [ENGINE=Memory]`, в SELECT, получающий данные, добавить `INTO tablename (fieldslist)`, а во второй процедуре использовать данные из этой таблицы.

Comment: Такой вариант я думал, он рабочий, но единственное, когда я вызываю свою первую процедуру во второй, использую данные из нее, мне вылазит датасет первой, который я не могу не возвращать, так как он нужен для других задач.

Comment: *когда я вызываю свою первую процедуру во второй, использую данные из нее, мне вылазит датасет первой, который я не могу не возвращать, так как он нужен для других задач.* Сливай его в таблицу - не будет ничего "вылазить". А "другие задачи" тоже будут общаться с созданной таблицей, а не с выходным потоком, ежели им надо.

Comment: Извини, но подскажи примерно как это сделать с точки зрения синтаксиса? Мне кажется, мы вернулись в начало, мне же нужно все-равно делать во второй процедуре call .... , чтобы получить таблицу с данными для второй процедуры

Comment: *мне же нужно все-равно делать во второй процедуре call .... , чтобы получить таблицу с данными для второй процедуры* Это ещё зачем? таблица-то уже имеется, просто греби из неё данные... Вот если таблицы нет, или она утратила актуальность - тогда другое дело, тогда по-любому надо вызывать формирующую её процедуру заново. Ну и не забывай, что для доступа к TEMPORARY таблице необходимо выполнять все процедуры в рамках одного и того же соединения, если соединения разные, то таблицу нужно делать статической (что не исключает размещения её в памяти).

Comment: Да, у меня как раз тот случай)  "что для доступа к TEMPORARY таблице необходимо выполнять все процедуры в рамках одного и того же соединения" - нужны актуальные данные и приходится вызывать процедуру заново, а она тулит свой датасет, где он не нужен))

Comment: Мне добавить к вышесказанному нечего. Всё уже не просто рассказано - разжёвано. Осталось понять и применить.